# Show that $Y(s)$ satisfies $(1+s^2)Y'(s) + sY(s) = 0$ for $ty'' + y' + ty = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I first approached the problem by finding the Laplace transform of $ty'' + y' + ty = 0$, such that:

$ts^2Y(s) - tsy(0) - ty'(0) + sY(s) - y(0) + tY(s) = 0. $

I solved for $Y(s)$:

$Y(s) = \frac{tsy(0) + ty'(0) + y(0)}{ts^2 + t + 2}$

But this is where I am stuck, as finding $Y'(s)$ by hand seems like a waste of time.

Thank you in advanced, any input helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using standard Laplace properties from tables,
\begin{align*}%
%TCIMACRO{\tciLaplace}%
%BeginExpansion
\mathcal{L}%
%EndExpansion
\left(  ty\left(  t\right)  \right)   &  =-Y^{\prime}\left(  s\right) \\%
%TCIMACRO{\tciLaplace}%
%BeginExpansion
\mathcal{L}%
%EndExpansion
\left(  y^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \right)   &  =sY\left(  s\right) \\%
%TCIMACRO{\tciLaplace}%
%BeginExpansion
\mathcal{L}%
%EndExpansion
\left(  ty^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \right)   &  =-Y\left(  s\right)
-sY^{\prime}\left(  s\right) \\%
%TCIMACRO{\tciLaplace}%
%BeginExpansion
\mathcal{L}%
%EndExpansion
\left(  ty^{\prime\prime}\left(  t\right)  \right)   &  =-2sY\left(  s\right)
-s^{2}Y^{\prime}\left(  s\right)
\end{align*}

Then
\begin{align*}%
%TCIMACRO{\tciLaplace}%
%BeginExpansion
\mathcal{L}%
%EndExpansion
\left(  ty^{\prime\prime}+y^{\prime}+ty\right)   &  =0\\
-2sY\left(  s\right)  -s^{2}Y^{\prime}\left(  s\right)  +sY\left(  s\right)
-Y^{\prime}\left(  s\right)   &  =0\\
Y^{\prime}\left(  s\right)  \left(  -1-s^{2}\right)  +Y\left(  s\right)
\left(  -2s+s\right)   &  =0\\
-Y^{\prime}\left(  s\right)  \left(  1+s^{2}\right)  -sY\left(  s\right)   &
=0\\
Y^{\prime}\left(  s\right)  \left(  1+s^{2}\right)  +sY\left(  s\right)   &
=0
\end{align*}